# Ошибки в карточке товара

Tags: javascript, битрикс

В карточки товара в консоли ошибка такого типа: The "eventObject" argument must be an object. Received type boolean.
Для примера можете сами заюзать
https://vita-nord.ru/catalog/lekarstvennye-preparaty-i-bad/vitaminy-mineraly-obshchetonizir-preparaty/obshchetonizir-preparaty-adaptogeny/obshchetonizir-pr-ty-adaptogeny-b-rets/51926/

Как примерно решать подобнобные ошибки.

Comment: Передавать объект, как аргумент функции, когда там ожидается объект, а не булево значение.

Comment: А как понять кто вызывал функцию если в консоли выводится только ошибка из метода который вызывается, без указания initiator ?